# Error during model selection: "Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite"

Tags: r, lme4, error-code

I want to perform a model selection with the 'glmulti' package.

I am using the following code:

```
form_glmulti = as.formula(paste("rrF ~ management + mNdep + mMAT + mMAP"))
lmer.glmulti<-function(formula,data,random="",...){
   lmer(paste(deparse(formula),random),data=regdata,REML=F,...)
}
glmulti_lmm<-glmulti(form_glmulti,random="+(1|PlotNR)",data=regdata,method="h",
                     fitfunc=lmer.glmulti, intercept=TRUE,marginality=FALSE,level=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in fn(x, ...) : Downdated VtV is not positive definite
```

What is VtV?